# Is there a way to rewrite the URL for WordPress admin to hide it from user with Rewrite API/add rewrite rule without mod_rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to change the custom URL rewrite to protect the site backend in WordPress. But I cannot do it without modifying the .htaccess. I would like to find the solution without having to rewrite mod_rewrite but not being able to do so.
Edit 1: It would be helpful if it's to be done without third party plugin.

Comment: Do you mean Setting and Permalinks?

Comment: there is a plugin for wordpress. for redirecting pages

Comment: @jeff Yes. That's what I meant. Can you please help.

Comment: @sanjundev Yes. But I'm trying to integrate it into the core function.php

Comment: Login to the admin side of your site. In the side panel locate the Settings option. From that select the Permalink option. Select what way you want your links to be displayed.